# How to merge two jsonNodes in one

Tags: java, kotlin, jackson-databind

I have two variables of class User as follows:

```
   val user1 = User().apply {....values here}
   val user2 = User().apply {....values here}
```

I want to create a JsonNode with the following structure:

```
   var node:JsonNode? = null
   node = {
    "user_1": {
       ...the fields of class User, assigned in variable user1
      },
    "user_2": {
     ...the values for user 2
    }
   }
```

I have converted the objects to nodes, but I do not know how to merge them using Jackson.

```
  val mapper1= ObjectMapper()
  mapper1.valueToTree<JsonNode>(user1)
  val mapper2= ObjectMapper()
  mapper2.valueToTree<JsonNode>(user2)
```

Or is there a more efficient way to create one json node structure with the two classes ?
I am using Kotlin and Jackson databank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested it, but I guess you should be able to simply create a `Map<String, User>` and convert *that* into a `JsonNode`:

```kotlin
val user1 = User().apply {....values here}
val user2 = User().apply {....values here}

val both = mapOf("user1" to user1, "user2" to user2)

val mapper = ObjectMapper()
val result = mapper.valueToTree<JsonNode>(both)
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you so much!!